# SetServiceStatus returns false, GetlastWin32Error has nothing to do with SetServiceStatus

Tags: c#, windows-services, pinvoke

I'm using `QueryServiceStatus` to receive current service status, and later set it's `waitHint` to 0, because default is 180000 as Process Hacker shows. And I would like to change other things like `controlsAccepted`. `QueryServiceStatus` works fine, but `SetServiceStatus` returns false, and `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` doesn't helps. It returns 183 which is ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (Cannot create a file when that file already exists.) as I assume this is from another application running at my computer.

```
IntPtr scm = WinAPI.Service.OpenSCManager(null, null, WinAPI.Service.SCM_ACCESS.SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
IntPtr service = WinAPI.Service.OpenService(scm, "mySvc", WinAPI.Service.SERVICE_ACCESS.SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);
var lpServiceStatus = new WinAPI.Service.SERVICE_STATUS();
bool queryStatus = WinAPI.Service.QueryServiceStatus(service, ref lpServiceStatus);
Svc.debugWr("queryStatus: " + queryStatus + (!queryStatus ? "LastWin32Error: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() : ""));
Svc.debugWr("checkPoint: " + lpServiceStatus.checkPoint);
Svc.debugWr("controlsAccepted: " + lpServiceStatus.controlsAccepted);
Svc.debugWr("currentState" + lpServiceStatus.currentState);
Svc.debugWr("exit code: " + lpServiceStatus.serviceSpecificExitCode);
Svc.debugWr("serviceType: " + lpServiceStatus.serviceType);
Svc.debugWr("Wait hint: " + lpServiceStatus.waitHint);
Svc.debugWr("Win32 exit code: " + lpServiceStatus.win32ExitCode);
lpServiceStatus.waitHint = 0;
Svc.debugWr("Wait hint: " + lpServiceStatus.waitHint);
bool setStatus = WinAPI.Service.SetServiceStatus(service, ref lpServiceStatus);
Svc.debugWr("setStatus: " + setStatus + (!setStatus ? "LastWin32Error: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() : ""));
```

Here's declarations of `SetServiceStatus`, `SERVICE_STATUS` and `QueryServiceStatus`

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool SetServiceStatus(IntPtr hServiceStatus, ref SERVICE_STATUS lpServiceStatus);
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool QueryServiceStatus(IntPtr hService, ref SERVICE_STATUS dwServiceStatus);
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SERVICE_STATUS {
    public int serviceType;
    public int currentState;
    public int controlsAccepted;
    public int win32ExitCode;
    public int serviceSpecificExitCode;
    public int checkPoint;
    public int waitHint;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the declarations of `SetServiceStatus` and `SERVICE_STATUS`.

Comment: You can not get a reliable error code out of GetLastWin32Error(), the pinvoke declaration is wrong.  Setting the SetLastError property to true is required.

Comment: Ok, now it gives ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE (6). I bevieve it's valid because function QueryServiceStatus works fine.

Comment: You've just changed the question. That's not fair. We answered the question that you asked. Please revert your last edit and ask a new question.

Comment: Wait, I want to solve why does `SetServiceStatus` doesn't work, I wrote "GetlastWin32Error has nothing to do with SetServiceStatus" just because you guys don't immediately ask to check it. Why would I leave an unworking function on my program?

Comment: If the question changes, especially code in the question changes, then answers go out of date. You would have been fine to add an update to the question, clearly marked, with the corrected code and the new error. But you must leave in the original incorrect version of the p/invoke dec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `GetLastWin32Error()` did not return a meaningful value is that your p/invoke declaration does not tell the framework to remember the last error code. You need your declaration like this:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
....
```

The call to `SetServiceStatus` fails because the handle you pass in the first parameter is indeed invalid. Look again at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686241.aspx). You are meant to pass a `SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE` but you pass a `SC_HANDLE`.

`SetServiceStatus` and `QueryServiceStatus` receive different types of handle. And you are passing the wrong one. The documentation for `SetServiceStatus` says that you need to pass:

> A handle to the status information structure for the current service. This handle is returned by the RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx function.